# Check input String from text file

Tags: java, jsp

Im using jsp and want to check if the input exists in the first column of the entire text file

let say I have **user.text** and contains
Test,FirstName,LastName
Test02,User,User08

If the user inputs "Test", it will print exist. otherwise it will add the inputs to file.

Here is my code:

```
    <% 
    String user= request.getParameter("user");
    String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
    String lastname= request.getParameter("lastname");

    File file = new File("/user.txt");
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));

    String line = read.readLine();

    if(line.contains(user)) {
        %>
        <H3>User Already exist...</H3>
        <%
    }
    else{
    outt.println(User + "," + firstname + "," + lastname + "\n");        
    outt.close();
    br.close();
    %> 
      <p> Done...</p>
     <%
   }
   %>
```

The problem it checks the first line only.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problem you are facing?

Comment: How about writing a `while` loop around the "read" and "check" part? Here is an example for reading the whole file with a `BufferedReader`: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a loop:

```
<% 
String user= request.getParameter("user");
String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
String lastname= request.getParameter("lastname");

File file = new File("/user.txt");
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));

String line = null;
while((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
    if(line.contains(user)) {
        %>
        <H3>User Already exist...</H3>
        <%
        break;
    }
}
if(line == null)
    outt.println(User + "," + firstname + "," + lastname + "\n");        
outt.close();
br.close();
%> 
  <p> Done...</p>
```

also, that validation (`line.contains(user)`) looks too error-prone...